# Docusign, email notifications issue

Tags: docusignapi

this is my scenario.

I've built an App integration with Docusign, works, and life is mostly good. Our Business has two use cases.

1. A client service rep create a form and sends to the client. Has been working since day 1.
2. We take a user through the embedded signing ceremony using the App integration. Works perfectly, except for:

When you hit the document, in the top left is says "Name wants you to sign", name being the owner of the template. Now that's me, but I'm a developer, we don't want that up there.

Easy enough? I create a support@brand.com user, should be fine, except, we ONLY want signing notifications to go to a sender when it's a manual form, NOT embedded. And there doesn't seem to be any way to specify a single user, or group notification settings.

I did find a concept called API user in the notifications part of settings, they're all turned off, and my work email(I'm the template owner) is still getting the notifications. Also can find zero documentation on what a API User is, outside of what would seem obvious, a form created by the API integration, however as I mention, it doesn't follow the rules we've set for it. As well it's business-critical that the support@brand does not get flooded with "signed" notifications.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Name wants you to sign" -- `Name` is the **sender** of the of the envelope, not the template owner.

To change to someone else you have some choices:

1. You can create a "system user." That's an email address / user in your DocuSign account such as "finance@your_company.com" If you use this type of system user then you will also need to decide how other people in your org who need access to the completed envelope will get access. Perhaps you'll cc them on the envelope. Or the envelope can be shared with others.
2. Individuals in your company can send out envelopes, then the from address will be from them.

#### API User

This no longer applies now that DocuSign uses OAuth.
Anyone with a user id on an account can use the API. You do not need to be an admin or have other special privileges to use the API.

#### Signing notifications

> we ONLY want signing notifications to go to a sender when it's a manual form, NOT embedded. And there doesn't seem to be any way to specify a single user, or group notification settings.

I don't understand your question. By manual form do you mean signing via email instead of embedded signing?

The best would be for you to ask a **separate question** on StackOverflow focused on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: So you're correct about it being my user_id, bit surprised.

It's odd, I thought it was the API integration which had a user_id, because that's where I got the information from, under the API and Keys tab. I guess it echos my admin user_id.

Comment: Correct, the "API User Id" in the Admin tool is simply the User ID of you--the person using the admin tool. The Admin tool has now been updated to label the field "User Id" instead of the previous "API User Id"

Comment: I found the solution to the 2nd part of the question. I logged in with the individual user, in my case the two `support` users. Went to their preferences, and unchecked all notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. As Larry pointed out(thank you) - it was the user_id passed, not the template owner, who's name was in the top left. I had thought the user_id given on the API page was specific to the integration, and not me, the user.

This allows me to solve for my use cases, and I can move forward.

Comment: PLEASE upvote all useful answers and CHECK (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. THANK YOU!